# Omniauth Strategies - Managing multiple users on a shared system

Tags: omniauth

I know what answers are going to be, but I just want to try my luck. Taking `Facebook` as an example say, I am using `omniauth-facebook` to allow users to log in to my site. Upon logging in, user may set up some privacy data on this site.

Taking up a scenario, I have 2 users `U1` and `U2`. They both have individually logged in using `Facebook` at my site and have respectively authorized the app. Now considering a shared system, `U1` comes to my site, clicks on `Login using Facebook`, authenticates herself and everything's okay. `U1` leaves but doesn't log outs from `Facebook`. Now `U2` comes, clicks on `Login using Facebook` and is automatically logged in using `U1`'s credentials. I am not storing user's `access_token` at any point.

Is there any way I can stop this from happening? The best I can come up with is add an intermediary page, in between authentication from FB and callback at my site, and ask user if this is the intended user from FB for her. If so, continue, else take her to login page. But this doesn't deal with the fact that `U2` can still see `U1`'s page.

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am targeting `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `LinkedIn` and `Google`. So I am looking for a common solution. I know there is a possibility of force-authentication for `Facebook` and `Twitter`, but I would like to implement a common solution.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook (and omniauth-facebook) provides the option `auth_type` to prevent just that:

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
    :auth_type => 'reauthenticate'
end
```

With this option, the user will be asked to enter his password when he trying to log in to your service using Facebook. Check out the [gem's documentation](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring) for more information.

One final note: this option only exists for omniauth-facebook. Other OmniAuth providers may have similar options, but others may have none at all. For example, Twitter has a `force_login` option that when set to `true` will logout the user from Twitter. Sometimes this is what you want, sometimes it is not. Logging out the user from other services can be quite bothersome. I'd actually like if all providers had these two options so we could choose which one to use (log out the user from the external service OR just ask for the password again) but I guess we'll have to be content with what we have. For example, as far as I know, Google has no protection for this risk.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't update my question. I came to know about this option yesterday. I formed this question with single provider in mind, but I wished to do this for `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `LinkedIn` and `Google`.

Comment: See my edited answer. There is no single option that works for every omniauth gem. You'll just to investigate those services' OAuth flows and their respective omniauth gems.